flutter how to add in table row and column?
how to display ProgramDayTable horizontal and ProgramDayTable display vertical as in the table below.
The problem is that I have tried all methods and have not reached a solution.

                             ProgramTable(title)


 ProgramDayTable(months)                |        ProgramDayTable(months)                | ...


    Day          |     Description      |         day        |     Description          | ...


ProgramDayTable(daye)| ProgramDayTable(des) |ProgramDayTable(daye)|   ProgramDayTable(des)  |

import 'package:addbird/models/ornithology/ornithology.dart';
import 'package:addbird/provider/program/program_provider.dart';
import 'package:addbird/widgets/column_widgets.dart';
import 'package:addbird/widgets/date_widgets.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:hooks_riverpod/hooks_riverpod.dart';

class DetailProgramForm extends HookConsumerWidget {
  const DetailProgramForm({
    required this.program,
    super.key,
  });

  final ProgramTableData program;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final theme = Theme.of(context);
    final programAsync = ref.watch(allProgram(program.id));

    return ColumnWidgets(
      children: [
        DateWidgets(icon: Icons.edit_calendar, date: program.updatedat),
        const SizedBox(height: 30),
        Column(
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              width: double.infinity,
              child: Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                  border: Border.all(
                    color: theme.colorScheme.outline.withOpacity(.1),
                  ),
                ),
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(program.title.toUpperCase()),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            programAsync.when(
              data: (data) {
                if (data != null) {
                  return Table(
                    border: TableBorder.all(
                      color: theme.colorScheme.outline.withOpacity(.1),
                    ),
                    children: [

                    ],
                  );
                } else {
                  return const Text('No data available');
                }
              },
              loading: () => const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
              error: (error, stack) => const Text('Error loading data'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

final allProgram = FutureProvider.family<Program?, int>((ref, id) {
  final notifier = ref.read(programProvider.notifier);
  return notifier.getAll(id);
});


Table
part of '../ornithology.dart';

@TableIndex(
  name: 'uniq_program',
  columns: {#title},
  unique: true,
)

/// programme de alimentation
class ProgramTable extends Table {
  IntColumn get id => integer().autoIncrement()();
  TextColumn get title => text()();
  TextColumn get updatedat => text()();
}

/// programme de alimentation par mois
class ProgramMonthTable extends Table {
  TextColumn get id => text()();
  IntColumn get program => integer().references(ProgramTable, #id)();
  TextColumn get months => text()();
}

/// programme de alimentation par jour
class ProgramDayTable extends Table {
  TextColumn get id => text()();
  TextColumn get months => text().references(ProgramMonthTable, #id)();
  IntColumn get daye => integer()();
  TextColumn get descriptions => text()();
}

class Program {
  Program({
    required this.id,
    required this.title,
    required this.month,
    required this.day,
    required this.updatedat,
  });

  final int id;
  final String title;
  final DateTime updatedat;
  final List<ProgramMonthTableData> month;
  final Map<String, List<ProgramDayTableData>> day;
}


I tried all methods but did not get the desired result
